# What's the point of this graph paper?

Tags: paper, paper-size

That might sound like a minor issue, but I'm wondering, what's the point of this paper?

[image]

The bigger squares are 1.2cm, and the smallers 4x4 are 3mm wide. It's originally a Spanish notebook.

I'm aware of multiple layouts for graph paper for different purposes: Chinese (stacked squares), Chinese training (stacked blocks, subdivided in 4 field), logarithmic paper, 10x per centimeter for design, 5 square/inch in the US, 4 squares/inch, French ruled paper, slanted grid for calligraphy, and so on.

But this seems like a unique design. Any idea, what's the intended audience?

Comment: 1.2cm exactly, or are you guesstimating? 'Roughly' 1.2cm would be 'roughly' half an old style Imperial [or American] inch… so the intended audience would likely be 'the USA'.

Comment: 1.2cm exactly. Not 1/2 inch.

Comment: Hi Quora Feans, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in my opinion, I don't think school material falls within the scope of graphic design. Anyway [here is a blog](https://www.materialescolar.es/blog/tipos-de-pauta-para-escribir/) (in Spanish but very easy to translate) explaining each kind of grid and its use.

Answer (score 2):

I used similar quadrille paper in engineering projects.

There's several cases where you'd want a 1/4 division:

> *IDEAL FOR GRAPH AND DRAFTING - 20 lb. basis, acid-free, versatile layout bond, printed with a non-reproducible blue grid on one side.*
>
> *WIDE USES - Grid paper is the type of graph paper most often used for art and drawing projects. It is used for creating floor plans,
>   designing web pages, creating cross-stitch patterns, planning
>   construction projects.*

[https://www.amazon.com/Alvin-Quadrille-Paper-Inches-1432-11/dp/B000HF6ZS4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000HF6ZS4)

Comment: The paper you linked to is different. In my original example, there 1.2cm squares, divided in 4x4 3mm squares.

Comment: You're right. 

Consider that perhaps there is *no* specific purpose to the dimensions of the graph paper.